# session is not working in uploadify plugin of jquery

Tags: jquery, uploadify

session is not working in uploadify plugin...

**Edit...**

@ marcgg 
When i am trying to upload images using uploadify plugin.. My session is nt working at back end..
Boss what else i can say.. should i post the default code i got from uploadify plugin...

Comment: What's going on? Care to show some code?

Comment: The title is longer than the question?!?  Can you give more info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flash doesn't forward cookies from the browser, so $_SESSION will not work correctly. (The code is most likely failing when you require_once the session  file.)

To summarize the concept:

1. Pass the session_id as a POST variable with Uploadify using scriptData
2. Manually call session_id($_POST['session_id']) prior to calling session_start();

this will also work..

```
         'scriptData': {'ts' : <?= time() ?>}
```

Comment: Actually, Flash does forward cookies. IE cookies. Regardless of the hosting browser. Nice, huh? An asp.net solution can be found here:http://skysanders.net/subtext/archive/2010/03/14/flash-uploaders-vs-asp.net-sessionstate-and-formsauthentication.aspx